# C++ pass-by-non-const-reference method inside pass-by-const-reference method

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, const-correctness, pass-by-const-reference

I have this function `pass_by_const(const std::string& s)` which wants to call `pass_by_non_const(std::string& s)`.

If I have this method's definition

```
pass_by_const(const std::string& s)
{
    pass_by_non_const(s);
}
```

would compiler yield at me, and are there work arounds ? I fear that `pass_by_non_const` modifies s behind my back.

Comment: If you're compiler allows this without so much as a warning, I'd get a new compiler. VC++ allows passing temps as non-const references, but even that is warned with appropriate (and in my opinion, mandatory) warning levels on.

Comment: it does. i just want to find the work around. it is just a convenient way to ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens with

```
pass_by_const(const std::string& s)
{
    pass_by_non_const(s);
}
```

is: `pass_by_const` has const argument `std::string s`, so it is not allowed to modify the string s defined in enclosing scope and passed to him as an argument. However, `pass_by_non_const` is allowed to modify s. This raises compiler error at compile time.

A local non-const copy of s can be passed to `pass_by_non_const` however. Then, the local copy may be modified in the scope of `pass_by_non_const`, whereas the enclosing scope's s passed as an argument to `pass_by_const` is not altered.

Right way to write the method is then

```
pass_by_const(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string local_copy = s;
    pass_by_non_const(local_copy );
}
```

No more compile time error, local_copy may be modified in most inner scope, whereas s from enclosing scope won't be, which abide by the pass-by-const-ref-ness of the `pass_by_const` method.

Answer (score 3):

You should not even *want* to call `pass_by_non_const` from `pass_by_const` because if an argument is a const reference you are "promising" to not modify it.

If you want to *violate* the type system (which is a bad thing), you could do ugly things like

```
 pass_by_const(const std::string& s)
 {
    pass_by_non_const(const_cast<std::string&>(s));
 }
```

But the point is that doing so is wrong, and could be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So anything bad could happen (a crash, or even the program accidentally doing what you want).

If you want to obey the type system and avoid violating invariants, make a local copy like suggested in [antitrust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129019/841108). Of course making a local copy might be costly.

Comment: i am not violating const correctness in my work around, and i still make sure that `pass_by_const` is not modifying passed by const ref argment.

Comment: @antitrust "i am not violating const correctness" - **you do.**

Comment: no: everybody respects its promise, pass by const ref method will never be allowed and be able to modify argument, even if calling a pass by non const method.

Comment: Well if the non const version doesn't modify anything just move the code into the const version and have the non const version call the const version. Why is this so difficult?

Comment: If a function does not modify anything it should be declared working on `const`

Comment: You cannot use `reinterpret_cast` to strip away cv-qualifiers.